# How Do I Access a Property of bound Object Instance with Knockout

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

I am unable to figure out how to get to a property of a bound item. The following does not work when the .name() is there.

```
<span data-bind='text: selectedMenuSection().name()'></span>
```

Seems you can't access a property of a bound object in the data-bind. The same syntax works in a model function, MenuViewModel.showSelection().  I've tried every conceivable syntax with no success. Below is an excerpt of my code.

Html

```
MenuSections: <select data-bind="options: leftMenu, optionsText: 'name', value: selectedMenuSection, optionsCaption: 'Pick...'"> </select>

Selected: <span data-bind='text: selectedMenuSection().name()'></span>

<button data-bind="click: showSelection">Show Selected Info</button>
```

javascript

```
 function MenuViewModel (menu) {
  var self = this;
  self.leftMenu = ko.observableArray(menu);

  //Bound to Select
  self.selectedMenuSection = ko.observable();

  self.showSelection = function(){
    alert(self.selectedMenuSection().name());
  };
};
```

Is it not possible to get to a databound object property or have I just not figured out how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the following:

```
<span data-bind="with: selectedMenuSection">
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
</span>
```

The first line makes sure that the inner span only exists if selectedMenuSection is not null or undefined (when you create self.selectedMenuSection, its value is undefined which can cause an error while trying to access the name property). The second line is your original binding. You don't need the `()` at the end, because you bind against the observable (you only need `()` to access the current value of the observable, or if you bind against a complex statement instead of directly to an observable).

Comment: That does work but and I can now get my code to work, this all makes me ponder much more with Knockout and how it works. I find that my code works if I place the following self.selectedMenuSection = ko.observable(menu[0]); in but does not work if I do this self.selectedMenuSection = ko.observable(self.leftMenu[0]);

Comment: That is because self.leftMenu is an observable(array), what you want is the underlying value: self.leftMenu()[0]. With knockout, the big trick is to know when you need the observable, and when you need the value.

Answer (score 0):

What does a MenuSection look like? I'm assuming that it has a name property that is not an observable. Hans's answer is the correct way to solve your problem. Understand the javascript object and understanding what 'context' you are in when you write your knockout html is very important.

The with binding changes the context from the root element ( the object you passed into your ko.applyBindings) to the context of the selectedMenuSection. So inside of that 'with' your context ( $data in all cases ) is a MenuSection. If you are every curious about what object is in the context you can do something like this:

```
    <div data-bind="with: selectMenuSection">
        <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data)></pre>
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    </div>
```

This will print out the current object context that you are in. You will then be able to see that you have a 'name' property available to you and whatever else is attached to a MenuSection.

Comment: Yes Matthew, MenuSection has a name property but it is observable. Thanks for the followup....I am curious. @Hans statement 'the big trick is to know when you need the observable, and when you need the value' has me more curious as well.

Comment: When in the bindings, if you are just using the value you don't need to access the value ( example : data-bind='visible: isVisible' ). But if you are doing any calculations you need to specify that you want the value ( example : data-bind='visible : isVisible() || isAdmin()' )

Hope that helps a bit.